# Does Concurrency::parallel_for has a command similar to omp_set_lock?

Tags: concurrency, set, locking, openmp, parallel.for

I have a class (say particle) which has a variable (say param1):

```
class particle
{
    double param1;
    . . .
    omp_lock_t particle_lck;
    . . .
};
```

and a std::vector containing some instances of the particle class,

```
vector <particle> Particles;
```

In omp parallel for loop, I use commands below to safely update "param1" in computations:

```
omp_set_lock(&currentParticle->particle_lck);
currentParticle->param1 += anything
omp_unset_lock(&currentParticle->particle_lck);
```

Now, I am going to convert my code from openMP to Concurrency library, I am wondering if there are any equivalent command to use in Concurrency::parallel_for loop instead of omp_set_lock, which can lock an object while is updating?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that += is not a complicated overloaded C++ operator and that "anything" can be executed safely in parallel,  you need to read up about OpenMP atomics, since by using them you can avoid the lock completely. (I know this appears off topic, but maybe you should consider std::atomic for param1, which will need some trickery since there are no float/double atomics in most C++ standards, but you can implement what you need with cmpxchg)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by Concurrency library you mean Microsoft's Concurrency Runtime. Your use case is actually a critical section and for that Concurrency provides the `concurrency::critical_section`, which is a non-reentrant mutex lock:

```
using namespace concurrency;

class particle
{
    double param1;
    . . .
    critical_section particle_lck;
    . . .
};
```

Then the critical section becomes:

```
currentParticle->particle_lck.lock();
currentParticle->param1 += anything;
currentParticle->particle_lck.unlock();
```

If you prefer a scoped approach, use `concurrency::critical_section::scoped_lock`:

```
{
   critical_section::scoped_lock guard(currentParticle->particle_lck);
   currentParticle->param1 += anything;
}
```

`scoped_lock` is a simple wrapper. It takes a reference to a `critical_section` object and calls `lock()` in the constructor and then `unlock()` in the destructor, so it releases the lock when it goes out of scope.

---

As explained by Jim Cownie, using locks for something that can be done more efficiently with an atomic operation, is an overkill. In OpenMP, one would usually do:

```
#pragma omp atomic update
currentParticle->param1 += anything;
```

Atomic operations in standard C++ require the use of special atomic types and those are only trully available for floating-point types starting with C++20, so your code will be (assuming C++20 compiler):

```
#include <atomic>

class particle
{
    std::atomic<double> param1;
    . . .
};
```

Updating the value:

```
currentParticle->param1.fetch_add(anything, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Concurrency does not provide its own atomic types. Instead, it relies on the `combinable` class to provide an equvalent to OpenMP's `reduction` clause.

Comment: Dear Hristo, thank you very much.
I tried #pragma omp atomic update, but did not gain any more efficiency. Off course, I am using VS2015 and /Ox optimization, also I omitted "update" keyword. Is it common?

Comment: @KhodaeiAhmadAli OpenMP 3.1 introduced four `atomic` subtypes, which captures better your intention and allows the compiler to use the proper low-level implementation. Those are specified using the `read`, `write`, `update`, and `capture` clauses, with `capture` being equivalent to the form without a clause. Visual Studio only supports OpenMP 2.0, so you cannot add `update` anyway.